# Setting a proxy (privoxy) via C# does not work

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

I'm trying to set a proxy with C# but it doesn't work. There's no exception thrown.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[...]
    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr IpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
    public static void Disable()
    {
        string proxyAddress = "192.168.1.101";
        int proxyPort = 8118;

        string proxySettings = $"http={proxyAddress}:{proxyPort};https={proxyAddress}:{proxyPort}";

        const int internetOptionProxy = 38;
        IntPtr proxySettingsPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(proxySettings);
        InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, internetOptionProxy, proxySettingsPtr, proxySettings.Length);
    }
```

Maybe someone can help me solve this question. It's a privoxy proxy server.

I don't know what the problem could be...

Comment: the third parameter is not a string. Have a look at: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet/internetsetoption.html?diff=y